# Append Datatable in VB

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, while-loop, dataadapter

I am developing windows app in `vb` where i want to append values in `datatable` withen a `while loop` as given below.

```
 If hscode <> "" Then
            da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & tablename & "] where [ItemNo] like '" & hscode & "%'", myConnection)
            da1.Fill(dt2)
            dtab = dt2.Clone

            dtab.Merge(dt2, True)


            Dim l As Integer
            l = 0
            For l = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
                dtab = dt2.Clone
                dtab.ImportRow(dt2.Rows(l))
            Next
            dt2.Clear()

        End If
```

In the above code when the `datatable` is populating for the first time its is taking only `one row` in `DTAB` `datatable`. and for the second time it is throwing an `error`. 
Can anybody please tell me how to `concatenate` two `datatable`. actually i want to show multiple database values in one `gridview` depending upon some `queries`.

Comment: why are you assgin dtab=dt2.clone in each loop execution

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code, but as it is now, there is no sense in filling a datatable (`dt2`), cloning its structure in another table (`dtab`) and then looping over `dt2` rows and import these rows in `dtab`.
You could simply fill dtab

However, assuming that you need dtab separate from dt2 for other reasons, then I think you could remove practically all of your code if you use the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) method of the DataTable

```
If hscode <> "" Then
     da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & tablename & "] where [ItemNo] like '" & hscode & "%'", myConnection)
     da1.Fill(dt2)
     dtab = dt2.Copy()
     dt2.Clear()
End If
```

Also, I think also that you should change your original query to avoid string concatenation and use a parameterized query like this

```
....
Dim queryText = "select * from [" & tablename & "] where [ItemNo] like ?"
da1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(queryText, myConnection)
da1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", hscode & "%")
....
```

This will avoid problems with Sql Injection and parsing of the hscode value.